# Парсер для Excel Exception

Tags: python

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WPython\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\WPython\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/xlsx/xls_hypertreading.py", line 92, in create_white_list
    self.progress["value"] = 0
  File "C:\WPython\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 438, in iter_rows
    max_row = max_row or self.max_row
  File "C:\WPython\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 344, in max_row
    rows = set(c[0] for c in self._cells)
  File "C:\WPython\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 344, in <genexpr>
    rows = set(c[0] for c in self._cells)
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

есть огромный xlsx, в нём размещенно куча строк в хаотичном порядке.
ячейки помеченые цветом, попадают в один список, 
ячейки без цвета в другой список, намного больше первого.
После чего пробегаюсь по спискам и некотарами индексами списка делаются матиматические вычесления.
с малениким xlsx в несколько тысяч строк, все работает быстро без исключений.
Но толькоко выбираешь большой, окошко tkinter подвисает на пару минут и
выьрасывает исключение.
пример кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример кода / текст ошибок нужно в виде текста предоставлять

Comment: Добавил скрин кода с threading, не работает почемуто тильда для кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы изменяете один и тот же словарь `self.progress` в разных потоках - это потоко-небезопасно.

[Здесь можно почитать о синхронизации потоков в Python...](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/)

В вашем случае гораздо выгоднее будет собрать все необходимые данные **за один проход** по Excel файлу и не использовать никаких потоков:

```
for row in self.wb.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value is not None:
            if str(cell.fill.start_color.index) == "00000000":
                self.white_tmp_list.append(cell.value)
            elif str(cell.fill.start_color.index) == "XXXXX":
                self.XXXXX_tmp_list.append(cell.value)
            elif str(cell.fill.start_color.index) == "YYYYY":
                self.YYYYY_tmp_list.append(cell.value)                    
            ...
```

Comment: ну первый раз я так и сделал, но у меня зависает окошко tkinter=(

Comment: если какой-то иной способ(быстрее), пройтись по всему xlsx, который вы знаете.
спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @AlexanderKoval, Pandas обрабатывает Excel гораздо быстрее, но он не умеет читать информацию о цвете ячеек... Можете попробовать [StyleFrame](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), но я с ним не работал...

Comment: @AlexanderKoval, что вы имеете ввиду под `con соединением`?

Comment: import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'D:\\Scripts\\DataScience\\ArticleScripts\\ExcelPython\\xl.xls')
sheet = wb.ActiveSheet
опечатка com

Comment: @AlexanderKoval, с `win32com` я не работал, думаю есть смысл сравнить скорость работы...

Comment: @AlexanderKoval, кстати вы сканируете все столбцы или один / несколько? В общем, чем больше будет информации о конретной задаче, тем качественнее будут ответы ;)

Comment: 0000000040;H;ZF07;40;20.8;
Записываю в таком виде в txt, и работаю с последними двумя цифрами, документ весит около 50 мб, и записано в хаотичном виде.
нужно все сканировать =(
спасибо вам) второй раз помогаете мне!